# php MySQL error for retrieving data

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I have a PHP code for selecting data from a database, but it produces `NULL` result, although the same query performed manually works well.  Here's relevant part of code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
if (!$conn) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_db_name($dbName,$conn);
$query = "SELECT Images.Path,p.NameAr,p.DescriptionAr FROM
                      (SELECT * FROM project where TypeID = 1) as p
                                      JOIN Images where Images.ProjectID = p.ID";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
var_dump($result);
```

What can be wrong about it?

Comment: How do you guys manage to have such unformated code? However, have you tested your query directly in mysql, to be sure that the problem does not exist on PHP, so the tag can be removed

Comment: Use are using `mysqli_` to connect and `mysql_` to fetch results.  Just use `mysqli_` for all the operations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about PHP related error but your query formation is not corect.
Change your query like below. Moreover, you are not fetching any column from images table then why do a join with images table?

```
SELECT Path,NameAr,DescriptionAr 
FROM
(
SELECT p.* FROM project p
JOIN
Images i on i.ProjectID = p.ID and p.TypeID = 1
) tab
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `mysqli_connect` but then you wrote `mysql_*`  If you fix all `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` it should work.